# One Select from five tables

Tags: abap, opensql

There are 5 types of web services `S1`,`S2`,`S3`,`S4`,`S5` that store their logs in separate tables `T1`,`T2`,`T3`,`T4`,`T5`. Logs of one service cannot get to the table of logs of another service.
There is a program that collects all these logs and generates one common log for all services. There is a temporary table `Temp_Tab`, which can contain all logs from all tables. So, in this program now to collect all the logs wrote 5 separate `select`, and this as you know, takes a very long time.
I want instead of these 5 `select` to write 1 `select` statement (Well, a maximum of 2) to shorten. 
Suggested that with OUTER JOIN-Ohm, but in JOIN-e necessary "common fields" to substitute after ON to specify the relationship. And in tables `T1`,`T2`,`T3`,`T4`,`T5` there is nothing in common and can not be, because there are logs on the operation of a particular service.

Comment: I don't understand. I see in `Final_tab` that the 4 columns of the first row have the values `b2`, `aa`, `cc1`, `v55`, which are a combination of values from Tab_B, Tab_A, Tab_C, Tab_E. So, do you mean that the result is a combination of all values from combinations of 4 from 5 tables? It means that the final number of rows will be very important and I don't think it's what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sandra for your comment. I'll try to describe you my real problem. I'll change my question.

Comment: 1) You have now completely rewritten the question, and you removed the parts about how to integrate the additional columns, so the answer proposed by petul is again valid from my point of view (using UNION). 2) I don't understand why JOIN would help you collect the tables 3) You assume that writing 1 SELECT would be faster than 5 SELECT but I don't see why you assume that. 4) I don't understand why you want to create a new table containing all these tables. Maybe explaining the whole problem would help people better answer.

Comment: Your new question makes no sense. All tables have nothing in common? How would you expect any collection into one unified table to work then? Please provide a sample structure of all tables, at least one row per table, and the expected structure and rows of the target table.

Comment: As you commented on petuls answer below, that the tables do not share any common column. (We're talking about logs, do they not even have a timestamp?) So how do you like to join them if UNION, as suggested by the first answer is not an option? Performance is not solely determined by the number of select statements and it my gut feeling is, we're actually dealing with a bad design choices or premature optimization.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [SELECT - UNION](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/index.htm?file=abapunion_clause.htm). Your target itab needs all relevant fields of course, or you use CORRESPONDING (if you specified additional fields in your select clause) or inline declaration with @DATA(). If required, the column names can be modified using aliases with AS.

Example:

```
SELECT a_id as id, a_name as name, a_descr as descr, a_value as value
  FROM tab_a
UNION ALL
SELECT b_id as id, b_name as name, b_descr as descr, b_value as value
  FROM tab_b
UNION ALL
SELECT c_id as id, c_name as name, c_descr as descr, c_value as value
  FROM tab_c
INTO TABLE @lt_temp_tab.
```

You can skip the *as* part if they have the same field name. Your text says so, your image doesn't.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Petul for your quick answer. `SELECT-UNION` is a good idea if I want to get only thes 4 fields, but I want All fields from All tables. Only thes 4 fields are same in thes tables, but the other fields are different.

Comment: @user11823122 Then select all columns (a.* and b.*) from a join based on the common fields

Comment: The main problem is with the common fields. There's no any common field. I can't write anything after `ON` in Join construction.

Comment: @user11823122 I'm confused. Before you updated the question their where common fields, like a~a_id = b~b_id

Comment: @user11823122, you don't need common fields with UNION. It can perfectly select all fields from all tables